# Using RegExp and match in JS getting back more than one match, but only want one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of `'image/png'`, the `'png'` could also be `'jpg'` `'gif'` `'jpeg'`. I have a `new RegExp(/^image[/](jpe?g|gif|png)$/)` which seems to work for the most part.

I use the `.match()` method and it returns an array like so `['image/png', 'png']`. I want it to return an array with `['image/png']`. I looked up some other post and saw the recommended `^$` for beginning and end and even tried the `\b` which is I think some type of word bound special character.

None of these are returning only the one match, which is what I want.

Expressions that should work:

```
'image/png' should return from match ['image/png'] not ['image/png', 'png']
'image/jpg' should return from match ['image/jpg'] not ['image/jpg', 'jpg']
'image/jpeg' should return from match ['image/jpeg'] not ['image/jpeg', 'jpeg']
'image/gif' should return from match ['image/gif'] not ['image/gif', 'gif']
```

Comment: Use `/^image[/](?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/`. The point is that you need to replace the capturing group with a non-capturing one.

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate, but coming at this problem from the other direction: [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)

Comment: Wouldn't that make it only return `png` though ?

Comment: Or you can try this: [`'image\/([^']+)'(?=])`](https://regex101.com/r/r8ZfO8/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think I am just to new to this, but from what I looked at the other post what you put would make it only return `'image'` would it not? I tried it and it worked, I just was wondering if you had some insight

Comment: It is easy: only match, do not capture.

Comment: You can put the answer if you would like and ill accept